# How to get shape of a pointer type tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I am interested in getting the value of the output tensor which is defined as pointer:

`Tensor* out = nullptr;`

I tried `out->get_shape()` which throws error:

```
error: 'class tensorflow::Tensor' has no member named 'get_shape'; did you mean 'set_shape'?
```

How to get the shape?

Comment: you can try, `out->shape()`;

Comment: I m trying to print using: `std::cout << "out = " << out->shape() << std::endl;`. It says: `error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const tensorflow::TensorShape')`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the shape of the tensor using ['shape()'](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#classtensorflow_1_1_tensor_1ad0065facf49e31e4f48f07dd41528119) fucntion, it will returns a `TensorShape`, to print the values you can use `.vec()` method

```
const TensorShape& out_shape = out.shape();
std::cout << "out = " << out_shape.dim_sizes() << std::endl;
```

Comment: `error: 'const class tensorflow::TensorShape' has no member named 'vec'.` ..Is this added in some latest version? M using 1.2.1

Comment: `dim_sizes` must work,. `.vec` is for tensor, It seems Tensorshape isn't considered here as tensor.

Comment: I tried out->dims() , it worked. Thanks for your help!